# Invalid high surrogate character (0xDEE1). A high surrogate character must have a value from range (0xD800 - 0xDBFF)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, aes

How can I fix this error, I tried `cardnumber` only is encrypted, and I have no problems in creating the xml file, when I already added the `expdate`. It prompts the error,

So far here is my code:

```
    cardnumber = cs_aes.Encrypt(cardnumber);
expdate = cs_aes.Encrypt(expdate);

XElement xml_request = new XElement("Request",
                new XElement("Transaction",
                    new XElement("CardNumber", cardnumber),
                    new XElement("CardMember", cardmember),
                    new XElement("ExpDate", expdate),
                    new XElement("Amount", amount),
                    new XElement("Invoice", invoice),
                    new XElement("Zip", zip),
                    new XElement("Street", street),
                    new XElement("Security", security),
                    ));

                    xml_request.Save(path here);
```

Encrypt/Decrypt code

Comment: Looks like your handmade `Encrypt` method returns something that is not valid string (most likely simply transforming byte sequence to string... instead of using something like Base64). Consider posting code for Encrypt.

Comment: @ok, i will update but my cardnumber is ok i can encrypt and decrypt

Comment: Please refrain from posting your encryption keys in a public forum... Now that you've done it, please make sure you create a new key and discard this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your GetString() method is broken.  You cannot store a byte[] in a string like that.  The byte values in a string are **not** arbitrary, they must adhere to the rules of a normalized utf-16 encoded string.  You were probably lucky by it choking early on a bad surrogate value, normalization also has the habit of randomly corrupting your data without you easily finding out about it.

You can use Convert.ToBase64String() to convert a byte[] to a string.

Comment: So i will use Converter.ToBase64String() ? so this will fix the issue? how about to convert back it to byte because i need it in my decrypt

Comment: Then you use Convert.FromBase64String().  I was kinda counting on that being obvious ;)

Answer (score 2):

As expected you code transforms byte sequence into a string by essentially casting byte array to char array and than to string.

This is bad idea since byte array may include sequences that are invalid/unacceptable in many contexts that expect valid strings:

- 0 character (two 0 bytes) likely cause many APIs to treat string as terminated at that character
- 0-31 characters are not printable/not allowed in XML
- invalid surrogate pairs will fail to render properly when trying to print/show on screen, also not allowed in XML
- many characters are not associated with visible representation.

Correct way to handle byte array/binary data is to either store as is (if storage format allows it) or encode (i.e. for XML base64 is recommended encoding).